# What does an http service spec actually test in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-httpclient

A bit of a theoretical question here.

I'm following the official [angular.io documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) to test a service that is doing http requests, and I successfuly implemented my spec, fine so far.

What I don't understand is what we are really testing here, providing that I specify the mock data that I should receive back from the request.

Differently put, how would I go about making this test fail?

What is `HttpClientModule` doing on the insides that makes this test worth implementing?

Don't get me wrong, I'm the first one to advocate for unit testing, I just don't understand what is the value that we are getting from this specific kind of spec.

Thank you very much for your time.

Cheers.

Comment: If you don't feel like there's anything to test, don't test it. No test is better than pointless test that you have to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This is to make sure that your service makes the HTTP call if it's methods are called and you can verify the HTTP called with 'GET/POST/PUT' etc.

As per documentation:

> Angular's HTTP testing library is designed for a pattern of testing wherein the app executes code and makes requests first.
>
> Then a test expects that certain requests have or have not been made,
>   performs assertions against those requests, and finally provide
>   responses by "flushing" each expected request.
>
> At the end, tests may verify that the app has made no unexpected
>   requests.

So if your service has a method `submitData` which puts the data to a Rest Service. Then in that case your test should verify if the submitData actually does it. Ex:

```
service.submitData(myRequestObj).subscribe(() => {
        expect(http.put).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(http.put).toBeCalledWith('service-url');
    });
```

Having said that, it's up to you if you feel like mocking and spying and testing a service or if there is no much value, you can just ignore.

Comment: That makes sense. So, we should only be testing that the requests are being formulated as we expect. The data layer test belongs in the backend part and here we should assume the format is correct. Thank you.

Comment: yes, just test if your requests are being made to backend, You can verify the url called, request Type (GET/POST etc), also mock response to see if the return type is expected.